# Streaming data and writing to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Just started investigating streaming data from one server to another. I'm using REQUEST and I have been able to PUT data from a file to another file on a separate server like so:

```
...
push: function(argv) {
  fs.createReadStream('source_test.json').pipe(request.put('https://path/to/server/'));
}
...
```

and

```
//server-side
router.put('/', function (req, res, next) {
  req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('dest_test.json'));
  res.status(200).end();
});
```

This works fine. Now instead I would like to write the contents to MongoDB and not a file. I'm fine writing "normal data" to MongoDB but I'm wondering what the typical approach is to write streamed data to a database. I assume I have to wait until the streaming has finished and then write to the DB?

Any advice would be much appreciated including advice on making the code more robust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that you stream your data in a form of a JSON document.

If you're streaming a single JSON documents, then you'll have to wait for it to arrive before passing it and sending to MongoDB driver.

But if you're streaming a set of documents, then you should be able to start processing them as soon as the first document will arrive.

First of all, there are two ways to steam a large set of JSON documents:

- using newline separated list of JSON documents (i.e. each line is a valid JSON document)
- using single JSON array

### Parsing newline separated JSON data

You could parse it with [`event-stream` module](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream):

```
var es = require('event-stream')

req
  .pipe(es.split())
  .pipe(es.parse())
  .pipe(es.map(function (doc, next) {
    collection.insert(doc, next);
  }))
```

You could use the same module to stream data from your MongoDB. Here is an example of doing it with [mongoose](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose):

```
collection
  .find()
  .stream()
  .pipe(es.stringify())
  .pipe(request.put(uri))
```

### Parsing JSON array

Parsing JSON array from a stream is a more difficult task, but you could do it using [`JSONStream` module](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream):

```
req
  .pipe(JSONStream.parse('*'))
  .pipe(es.map(function (doc, next) {
    collection.insert(doc, next);
  }))
```

And to stream data from MongoDB:

```
collection
  .find()
  .stream()
  .pipe(JSONStream.stringify())
  .pipe(request.put(uri))
```

**N.B.** Make sure that you're not using [`body-parser` middleware], or any other middleware that will attempt to parse incoming JSON data for you, because it'll nullify all benefits from using `JSONStream`.

Comment: the es.map part is confusing me, how can I avoid that I start a huge amount of insert operations? I want to wait for each insert operation to finish before the next one is started.